Flask -keep checkboxes and their checked values in the page even after submit button is clicked
i want the checkboxes to stay in the left div with its previously checked values even after generate button is submitted.
I divided page into two(similar to streamlit sidebar).
first user will check the checkbobes and then submit the generate button, a tabble and picture is shown in right side div which is from generate funtion in python. here after this checkboxes goes away after button submit. i want them to stay and le the user change it anytime and work accordingly.
Fronth end is not my cup of tea.
I have started to learn so please help.
@app.route('/')
def index():

    table_names = get_table_names()
    return render_template('combined.html', table_names=table_names,db_name=database)

@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    import time
    selected_tables = request.form.getlist('table')
......
    return render_template('combined.html', tables=[data_dict.to_html(classes='data')], titles=[''],graph_done=graph_done)

this is combined.html
<body>

    <div id = "container">

  <div class="left">


    <form method="post" action="/generate">
        {% for table_name in table_names %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="table" value="{{ table_name }}" >{{ table_name }}<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_tables" value="{{ selected_tables|join(',') }}">

        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
      {% if tables %}
        {% for table in tables %}
            {{ titles[loop.index] }}
            <table class="table-container" style="margin: 0 auto;"> <!-- Center the table -->
                {{ table|safe }}
            </table>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
    </div>
</body>

i want the checkboxes to stay even after button is submitted.

You can you session to achieve this:
from flask import session

# Set Up a Secret Key
app.secret_key = 'BAD_SECRET_KEY'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    
    # Initializing selected_tables variable
    if 'selected_tables' not in session.keys():
        session['selected_tables'] = []

    table_names = get_table_names()
    return render_template('combined.html', table_names=table_names,db_name=database)

@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    import time
    selected_tables = request.form.getlist('table')

    # Updating selected_tables variable
    session['selected_tables'] = selected_tables
......
    return render_template('combined.html', tables=[data_dict.to_html(classes='data')], titles=[''],graph_done=graph_done)

Now you can access selected_tables variable in your combined.html via session object:
{% for table_name in table_names %}
<input type="checkbox" name="table" value="{{ table_name }}" {{ 'checked' if table_name in session['selected_tables'] }}>{{ table_name }}<br>
<input type="hidden" name="selected_tables" value="{{ selected_tables|join(',') }}">

{% endfor %}

